Do small electrical field generators generate "different" electrical fields than long antennas - how to measure?
Modern electronic devices often generate electrical fields in the frequency range of 10-50kHz.
I want to distingush 2 categories:

Loaded onto mains (e.g. solar inverters) and then mains wiring emits into space at long distances away from the power source
emitted directly into near space from small internal components

I measure these electrical fields with an grounded oscilloscpe (70pF), its probe and a 50cm wire attached to the probe as antenna. Let's assume the following physical situation: I have spot A with electrical field 1 (loaded onto mains 1m away from mains wiring) and another spot B with electrical field 2 (emitted directly 1m away from the emitting device) and by accident at both spots my oscilloscope shows the same voltage so with my current knowledge I assume the electrical fields to be the same.
In this physical situation, is there another measurement setup/device which can distingush these two spots/categories (by showing different voltages for example)? I want the position of the measurement device to be fixed at spot A or B so no measuring of how fast the electrical field weakens with distance.
I strongly have the feeling that these two categories can be distinguished and I miss a concept for this (connection between ground and the source, measuring with higher impedance?!) and I want to know how to measure this, but maybe there is no difference, so it can't be measured.

Are you asking how to perform the measurement, or are you asking if the electric fields, at a point, from these two processes are different?  Please edit your question so that it is complete in this regard.

I want to measure it - I specified the question

Oscilloscope does not measure electric field, but potential difference (if the leads are properly shielded and probes are touching conductors). Potential difference characterizes two points of space, and that difference being the same for one pair of points as for the other pair does not imply same electric field at both pairs.

One potential is the 50cm wire in space acting as electrically short antenna for the electrical field in space, this is the conductor connected to the probe. Other potential is the ground, also connected as conductor. Should I create a question if this measurement setup really is measuring electrical fields?

You can challenge my measurement setup for electrical fields in general here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/809527/measure-electrical-fields-in-space-with-oscilloscope-and-wire

What you are talking about, in electronics engineering terms, are conducted and radiated emissions.
Radiated emissions is the stuff that's escaping the device as electromagnetic waves directly.
Conducted emissions is the stuff that's escaping the device via the power wires or any other connections to the device.  Conducted emissions can be further broken down into common-mode (i.e., there's bulk current flowing back and forth on the power or other cable), and differential mode (i.e., the sum of the currents on all of the conductors in a cable is zero, but there's still power being conducted down the cable).
I honestly don't know how to properly set up a lab to do the measurements separately, so I'm not going to comment heavily on that.  Conducted and radiated emissions are common specifications for devices, and there's regulatory requirements on various consumer and industrial devices as to how much they're allowed to emit.  So with some digging on those search terms, you should be able to find some setups and see how it's done.

The conducted emissions then radiate from the wire.
Radiated emissions can be made to potential differences (=conducted) via antennas.
So there is a certain connection. I could buy a electrical field antenna for some hundreds of euros but I want to know first what makes it so expensive.

Radiated emissions: I thought that you can only talk about electromagnetic waves in far-field, but my situation is about near fields.
