Measure electrical fields in space with oscilloscope and wire
I have an oscilloscope with its standard probe. Combined they have 1MOhm resistance and 71pF capacitance.
I attach a 50cm wire floating in space to the probe and connect the ground clip of the probe to earth.
How good is this measurement setup for measuring radiated electrical fields?

It depends on the minimum detectable current/voltage of your oscilloscope. Also note that in general there will be all sorts of stray fields, making any detection very hard. This is why FM radio antennas have an additional tuning circuit to only select certain frequencies.

Minimum detectable current/voltage is no problem as long as I can see values. And yes, I always see values from "stray fields". And that is what I want: see a good frequency range, not only a certain signal.

I would set up a small triode with a long wire attached to the control grid and take O-scope readings of the plate voltage. You could do something similar with a transistor or OP amp if you wanted.

Just want to point out that Nyquist noise would show up as "white", i.e. nearly constant strength signal across the frequency range, so you need to makes sure that your o-scope is not just picking up thermal noise. Are you for example, picking up much 60Hz signal from the walls?

@AlbertusMagnus: I don't have problems with white noise, most spectrum is at oscilloscope noise floor of -105dBU. I pick up a lot 50Hz (in Germany instead 60Hz) signal from my walls. I get AM radio aliases, especially at night, but there are some tricks like measuring higher maximum frequency than needed.

@AlbertusMagnus: As long as I can measure some electric field, I don't need an amplifier (this will be another project of mine). Maybe there is some valid point like "You measure with too low impedance, get a shorter wire" then I need an amplifier, but not with the described measurement setup.
